# clone(serialize) v. serialize(clone)

Tags: javascript, serialization, design-principles, construction

My objects `serialize()` method is dependent on a call to its `clone()` method, because of its options to get rid of unwanted data without changing the original instance:

```
serialize: function(opt_filters) {
    // Cloning even if not filtering.
    var clone = this.clone().applyFilters(opt_filters);
    return clone.doWhatsNeeded();
}
```

But the `.clone()` function uses `.serialize()` to construct a new instance.

I was wondering if there is a design principle/pattern that provides guidance on which method to resolve the endless loop in (and which, if followed properly, would avoid that situation from coming up again)?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I don't see a problem. Presumably the `clone` function will never filter, so you'll never call back into `clone`.

Comment: @BenAaronson thanks, I summarized incorrectly, fixed.

Comment: @Snowman javascript - tried to simplify without having it look too much like python ;)

Comment: @bebbi each language has slightly different semantics around cloning and serialization. Specifying the language is important for this type of question, as opposed to a more pure whiteboard/design type of question.